# Clean visualization of a large graph with graphivz

Tags: graph, graphviz

I am trying to visualize a social network using graphviz. I have used already many variations of dot, fdp, sfdp, neato, etc.,

for instance,  `sfdp -Tpng test1.dot -o test1.png`

I also have tried to split the graph in regions of clusters using the `cluster` utility and some other commands such as `overlap=false`. However, none of my current attempts have generate a clean visualization of the graph. By clean I mean to visualize the graph without overlaps and better distribution of the nodes.

two of my attempts are in this link [dot script](https://gist.github.com/huberflores/131a7e45198eecbd41a8)

Since the number of the nodes is large, locating the nodes manually is out of the question. So, I am wondering if there is a way to achieve a better automatic distribution of the graph in graphivz? Any suggestions would be appreciate it. Thanks in advance.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's [a version in neato with some modifications](https://gist.github.com/michaeloboyle/f5498d583fbc8f68b8d7):

[image]

It prevents the lines from overlapping the nodes and adds color to help identify the clustering.

You might also want to check out http://socilab.com/ for some ideas on visualizing social networks.

Comment: Definitively, this looks much better and understandable. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I used circo to get a better visualisation (attention: takes *very* long). This works but results in a very large graph. By the way - do you use a script to generate the file? There is ample room to make it more concise if not.